# Why SUPEE-10888 is requested on magento 1.9.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I scan my website on magentary.com, it says "SUPEE-10888: Vulnerable, immediate attention required. Patch not detected." but the version is 1.9.4.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: One possibility is that 10888 can not be detected remotely. This is claimed by the magereport.com scanner. The other is that some extension or customization has overridden the core and reopened a vulnerability closed by 10888.

Comment: Actually I'm scared abotu this second case. Any suggestion about how to find the possible vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

SUPEE-10888 is a new security patch for Magento 1 which addresses 12 security issues.

SUPEE-10888, Magento Commerce 1.14.3.10 and Open Source 1.9.3.10 contain multiple security enhancements that help close cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and other vulnerabilities.

here is a link to get more info

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10888

Comment: Magento 1.9.4.10 contains all the patches (10888 too), so my question is: why with magento 1.9.4.10 magentary.com says that supee-10888 is not installed?